# Views fields as Columns in table

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called **Pets**, which only has title and description. In Pets there are only 3 data (set by Admin) Cats, Dogs and Mouse. User can select only from these data and cannot add more Pets.

After the Girls register in the site they can hit the checkbox to select the pets they have in their profile.

However, I want to have a Views table where I want to list the Girls' profile like: (that's the table I wanted to make)

**Name** ------ **Age** -------- **Dogs** ---------- **Cats** ----------- **Mouse**
Tina ----------- 21 ------------ Yes ---------------- No ----------------- No
Lita ----------- 27 ------------- No ---------------- Yes ----------------- Yes

When I add **Pets** title in the views it just shows as:

**Title**
Dogs
Cats
Mouse

but I want to change the fields(dogs, cats, mouse) as Columns and have **Yes** or **No** in the rows. I just tried [Views Flipped Tables Module](https://drupal.org/project/views_flipped_table) but wasn't able to do with it. any suggestions please ?

Comment: It all depends on a way you used to create link between user and node.

Comment: like? for a moment forget about the link between user and node, I will look into combining it later, but How do I change the fields as row to fields as columns. In contrast to above question, leave the Name and Age out, how can I change the Dogs, Cats and Mouse as Columns and have Yes and No as fields? I tried with filter, but it can only help with one field

Comment: You have 3 nodes, Dogs, Cats and Mouse. How did you created field on user profile? What module / technique you used?

Comment: I created new Content type called Profile and added Pets content type as Node Reference/ entity reference

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Views aggregation.

1. Define the relationships of the fields.
2. Under Advanced > Other enable aggregation
3. Add fields of the animal nodes and define the grouping as "count" in the field's aggregation settings.
4. Define no results bahaviour as "No" and rewrite the result as "Yes". Define 0 as "no result". All in the field settings.

Hope that helps!

cheers,
j

Answer (score 0):

[Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) does it. 
You don't necessary have to aggregate but it make a table as you want

Answer (score -1):

In View -> "HEADER" section is available know.. Write HTML as separate table.

```
 <table><tr>
<th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Dogs</th><th>Cats</th><th>Mouse</th>
</tr></table>
```

and for field settings make it as grid.. and also you require above Views Flipped Table module. It's my small suggestion.

Comment: if only I had privilege of using grids... I have very huge set of data, and table is the preference by customer, so, it can be exported to xls. If it was just front end preference, I'd create new views-tpl.php and hack the lines with jquery to display all the informations as clients want, but I don't have that luxury